# How to create a third database table from two database tables comprised of users and schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I'm working on a side project where a user can login to a site where all the sports matches for that day are displayed. The user can pick which teams they think will win that day. Users can form groups to compare who has made the most accurate predictions that day, and over time.

I have a first table `Matches` with about 900 rows and a `Users` table. I'm thinking that instead of storing the results of the user picks in either of those existing tables, I should create a third table called `Picks` with columns `user id` as well as `match id` and store as a string the name of the team that the user has picked for that particular match id. I would have a `winner` column either in the `Picks` or `Matches` table and if the pick matches the `winner` for that `match id`, the user gets credit for it.

Is this the right way to do this? Am I walking into a trap here?

Comment: I think it is a good idea to have a third table Picks where you can store the 3 columns. But I would sugest to have the winner column in the Matches table, it seems more logical to have it there. Also you might want to replace using string for the team the user picked and maybe use numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store the actual team from the match that the user selected, not both the team and match separately.  In this case, you may have something called a match_team.  This table would hold the detailed information about that particular team in that match.  This would be done like...

```
Users
  :name
  :email
  :password

Picks
  :user_id
  :match_team_id

Matches
  :date
  :location
  :winning_team_id

MatchTeams
  :match_id
  :team_id
  :score
  :home_team?
```